# m piles of coin with different value, you are only allowed to get coins from the top. Assuming you can take n coins home, what is the max value?

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming, backtracking

The question is described above. Basically, the input is `vector<stack<int>>& piles` and `n`, output is the max value for all `n` coins from any of the piles.

The only solution I can think of is to use backtracking for each pile, i.e. `piles[0]` is chosen `i` coins, then recursively call functions on `piles[1...m-1]` and `n - i`. And record max value for all possible combinations. I feel like this can be solved by dynamic-programming, however, due the constrain `n`, it's hard for me to build a dp equation.

Any better solution than backtracking?

Comment: What is the problem source? Also what is the limit of m & n & coins value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are m piles. Every pile p offers n+1 contributions of 
`(label, gain, cost)`:
for i from 0 upto n have `("pile {p}, {i} taken", sum of top i values, i)`.

The sum of costs must be equal (or less when negative numbers) to n, gain maximal.

The rest is up to the algorithm: whether you sort descending by `((double)gain)/cost` or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

This is definately nHr combination.
I would use some code like this.. p = number of piles, n = coins taken.
calc_sum is a function to record maximum value.

```
nHr h(p, n);
while(h.next()) {
    for(int i=0; i<h.size(); i++) take_coins_from_a_pile(h[i]);
    calc_sum();
}
```

And this is nHr library of my own.

```
#pragma once
#include <exception>

class NRexception : public std::exception
{
public:
    virtual const char* what() const throw() {
        return "Combination : N, R should be positive integer!!";
    }
};

class Combination
{
public:
    Combination(int n, int r);
    virtual ~Combination() { delete [] ar;}
    int& operator[](unsigned i) {return ar[i];}
    bool next();
    int size() {return r;}
    static int factorial(int n);

protected:
    int* ar;
    int n, r;
};

class nCr : public Combination
{
public: 
    nCr(int n, int r);
    bool next();
    int count() const;
};

class nTr : public Combination
{
public:
    nTr(int n, int r);
    bool next();
    int count() const;
};

class nHr : public nTr
{
public:
    nHr(int n, int r) : nTr(n,r) {}
    bool next();
    int count() const;
};

class nPr : public Combination
{
public:
    nPr(int n, int r);
    virtual ~nPr() {delete [] on;}
    bool next();
    void rewind();
    int count() const;

private:
    bool* on;
    void inc_ar(int i);
};

#include "combi.h"
#include <set>
#include<cmath>

Combination::Combination(int n, int r)
{
    //if(n < 1 || r < 1) throw NRexception();
    ar = new int[r];
    this->n = n;
    this->r = r;
}

int Combination::factorial(int n) 
{
    return n == 1 ? n : n * factorial(n-1);
}

int nPr::count() const
{
    return factorial(n)/factorial(n-r);
}

int nCr::count() const
{
    return factorial(n)/factorial(n-r)/factorial(r);
}

int nTr::count() const
{
    return pow(n, r);
}

int nHr::count() const
{
    return factorial(n+r-1)/factorial(n-1)/factorial(r);
}

nCr::nCr(int n, int r) : Combination(n, r)
{
    if(r == 0) return;
    for(int i=0; i<r-1; i++) ar[i] = i + 1;
    ar[r-1] = r-1;
}

nTr::nTr(int n, int r) : Combination(n, r)
{
    for(int i=0; i<r-1; i++) ar[i] = 1;
    ar[r-1] = 0;
}

bool nCr::next()
{
    if(r == 0) return false;
    ar[r-1]++;
    int i = r-1;
    while(ar[i] == n-r+2+i) {
        if(--i == -1) return false;
        ar[i]++;
    }
    while(i < r-1) ar[i+1] = ar[i++] + 1;
    return true;
}

bool nTr::next()
{
    ar[r-1]++;
    int i = r-1;
    while(ar[i] == n+1) {
        ar[i] = 1;
        if(--i == -1) return false;
        ar[i]++;
    }
    return true;
}

bool nHr::next()
{
    ar[r-1]++;
    int i = r-1;
    while(ar[i] == n+1) {
        if(--i == -1) return false;
        ar[i]++;
    }
    while(i < r-1) ar[i+1] = ar[i++];
    return true;
}

nPr::nPr(int n, int r) : Combination(n, r)
{
    on = new bool[n+2];
    for(int i=0; i<n+2; i++) on[i] = false;
    for(int i=0; i<r; i++) {
        ar[i] = i + 1;
        on[i] = true;
    }
    ar[r-1] = 0;
}

void nPr::rewind()
{
    for(int i=0; i<r; i++) {
        ar[i] = i + 1;
        on[i] = true;
    }
    ar[r-1] = 0;
}

bool nPr::next()
{   
    inc_ar(r-1);

    int i = r-1;
    while(ar[i] == n+1) {
        if(--i == -1) return false;
        inc_ar(i);
    }
    while(i < r-1) {
        ar[++i] = 0;
        inc_ar(i);
    }
    return true;
}

void nPr::inc_ar(int i)
{
    on[ar[i]] = false;
    while(on[++ar[i]]);
    if(ar[i] != n+1) on[ar[i]] = true;
}
```